# Getting LastPass to work like SuperGenPass

Tags: password-management, lastpass, supergenpass

I have just recently switched from SuperGenPass to LastPass because the master password cannot be changed with SuperGenPass.

Now with SuperGenPass to would type in your usename and master password in the login screen and active the SuperGenPass script bookmarklet, which would replace the master password with the correct (generated one). This is the behaviour that I want. No autocomplete of either username or password. When you've filled in both fields to just click the bookmark (or a short-key would be best) and LastPass would take over and fill in the correct password.

Is this possible with LastPass and how would I do that?

Comment: you can obviously change the "master" password with supergenpass: just use another one. but obviously you have FIRST log into a site with your old password and then create the new one (with the new master password). and you have to do this for every site you visited with the old master.

Comment: Obviously this works, but it's not really all that user friendly :-)